# Migrate a question to DataScience.SE

Tags: discussion, migration

I haven't find a dedicated "migrate question" thread, so I do it by case.

This question:

- https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38813/how-to-deal-with-large-amounts-of-binary-data

is IMHO great, but on technical aspect of data, which are perpendicular to academia. I voted to close it (with the intent of migrating to https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

How can move it and how?

Comment: I have migrated the question.

Comment: Note that at least [SO does not encourage migration to sites in beta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169983/256777) - from [the accepted answer there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169984/256777): "Migrating to beta sites isn't something we encourage because beta should be all about a site figuring out its own voice rather than getting questions from elsewhere, but an occasional migration doesn't hurt much."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I talked about this in chat a few weeks ago (http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20033769#20033769). Users cannot generally migrate questions. Just flag questions that you think should be migrated and a mod will take care of it.